# Get Outlook AppointmentItem using GlobalAppointmentID

Tags: c#, search, outlook, com-automation

I am developing a calendar for my firm that synchronizes with Outlook Calendar.

Atm I can:

- import appointments from Outlook and show them in my calendar
- update my appointments when Outlook appointments get updated
- create Outlook appointments when appointments get created in my calendar

The only issue I have is updating/deleting Outlook appointments when my appointments update/delete.

I have the GlobalAppointmentID of the corresponding appointments but I can't seem to search on that ID.

I tried:

```
using Microsoft.Office.Interop;

private void GetAppointment(string myGlobalAppointmentID)
{
Outlook.Application oApp = new Outlook.Application();

Outlook.NameSpace mapiNamespace = oApp.GetNamespace("MAPI");

Outlook.MAPIFolder calendarFolder = mapiNamespace.GetDefaultFolder(Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderCalendar);
Outlook.Items outlookCalendarItems = calendarFolder.Items;

Outlook.AppointmentItem appointmentItem = (Outlook.AppointmentItem)outlookCalendarItems.Find("[GlobalAppointmentID] = '{0}'", myGlobalAppointmentID));

//update or delete appointmentItem here (which I know how to do)
}
```

I keep getting 'Condition is not valid' Exception.
Apparently Outlook does not allow to search on binary properties (such as GlobalAppointmentID).

I use the same outlookCalendarItems.Find() and calendarFolder.Items.Restrict() without problems in other instances.

I tried using Redemption but I couldn't get it to work either.
Does anybody have experience or a suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I ended up doing after looking further:
I added a text UserProperty where I put the GlobalAppointmentID("GAID") in.
You can Filter on those.
And it seems to do the trick.

```
private void AddGAIDIfNeeded(Outlook.AppointmentItem app)
        {
            bool GAIDexists = false;
            if (app.UserProperties.Count != 0)
            {
                foreach (UserProperty item in app.UserProperties)
                {
                    if (item.Name == "GAID")
                    {
                        GAIDexists = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }

            if (GAIDexists == false)
            {
                app.UserProperties.Add("GAID", Outlook.OlUserPropertyType.olText);
                app.UserProperties["GAID"].Value = app.GlobalAppointmentID;
                app.Save();
            }
        }
```

And to find a specific AppointmentItem:

```
private void DeleteOutlookAppointmentByGAID(string globalAppointmentID)
        {
            Outlook.Application oApp = new Outlook.Application();
            Outlook.NameSpace mapiNamespace = oApp.GetNamespace("MAPI");
            Outlook.MAPIFolder calendarFolder = mapiNamespace.GetDefaultFolder(Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderCalendar);
            Outlook.Items outlookCalendarItems = calendarFolder.Items;

            try
            {
                Outlook.AppointmentItem appointmentItem = null;
                appointmentItem = outlookCalendarItems.Find(String.Format("[GAID] = '{0}'", globalAppointmentID));

                if (appointmentItem != null)
                {
                    appointmentItem.Delete();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                classExecptionLogging.LogErrorToFolder(ex);
            }

        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, OOM won't let you search on binary properties (as well as recipients or attachments), but [Redemption](https://www.dimastr.com/redemption) (I am its author) should work. The following script (VBA) worked just fine for me:

```
  set Session = CreateObject("Redemption.RDOSession")
  Session.MAPIOBJECT = Application.Session.MAPIOBJECT
  set Folder = Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderCalendar)
  set appt = Folder.Items.Find("GlobalAppointmentID = '040000008200E00074C5B7101A82E00800000000D0FECEE58FEAD70100000000000000001000000041C887A3FA12694F8A0402FEFFAD0BBB'")
  MsgBox appt.Subject
```

Answer (score 0):

The Outlook object model doesn't support searching for binary properties such as `GlobalAppointmentId` (any other `PT_BINARY` property) with `Items.Find`/`Items.FindNext`/`Items.Restrict`.

The only workaround is to loop through all item in the `Calendar` folder (which is inefficient) or search using Extended MAPI (or using third-party wrappers such as Redemption.

Comment: I will have a look into Extended MAPI. TY for responding